# Safari displays transition ease-in effect wrong

Tags: html, css, safari, css-transitions

I have an itembox with a background and in it a textbox with a headline and text.
On hover the textbox expands over the whole element and displays the text.
On mouse out the textbox shrinks and only the headline is visible again.
This works fine in every browser except Safari 9.1 on Mac.

In Safari the expand effect works, but on mouseout the textbox jumps to the top of the itembox, flickers a bit and then jumps back to the middle. What must i do that it works in Safari like in the other browsers?

Here is the whole code Snippet http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qNOrwm

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 item">
  <div class="box item-outer" style="background-image:url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=background&w=700&h=894&bg=00F33F')">
    <div class="item-inner">
      <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="headline">Project</div>
        <div class="content">Lorem ipsum...</div>
      </div>
      <div class="more">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-teaser">read more <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="see-more">
        <div>more</div>
        <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 0rem;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.item .item-outer {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 140%;
  background-color: #d9e0cd;
}
.item .item-outer .item-inner {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 10rem;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  right: 0.5rem;
  left: 0.5rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin-top: 0;
}
.item .item-outer:hover .item-inner {
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  transform: none;
}
.item .item-outer .item-inner .content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  bottom: 3rem;
  left: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.item .item-outer .item-inner .content-wrapper .headline {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.item .item-outer:hover .item-inner .content-wrapper .content {
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
}
.item .item-outer .item-inner .content-wrapper .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
  color: transparent;
  display: none;
}
.item .item-outer .item-inner .more {
  display: none;
}
.item .item-outer:hover .item-inner .more {
  display: block;
}
.item .item-outer .item-inner .more {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1rem;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.item .item-outer .item-inner .more .btn-teaser {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.item .item-outer .item-inner .see-more {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0.25rem;
  left: 0;
}
.item .item-outer:hover .item-inner .see-more {
  display: none;
}
```